# Less: error evaluating function data-uri: Cannot find module './types.json'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I'm receiving the following error after upgrading Visual Studio 2013 Web Essentials recently:

> Less: error evaluating function data-uri: Cannot find module
>   './types.json'

This is because of the following line of code, but I see no reason why it should all of a sudden start causing an issue:

```
background-image:data-uri('../images/search.png');
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem on a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1939).

The issue is caused by Web Essentials and can be resolved by carrying out the following steps:

- Download `types.json` from https://github.com/broofa/node-mime
- Copy to the following folder location:
- C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\0hrky2tf.4y5\Resources\nodejs\tools\node_modules\mime

As the original GitHub discussion mentions, `0hrky2tf.4y5` is generated and therefore will differ for each user.

I carried out these steps and it immediately fixed my issue.

Comment: Thank you Curt. I had this same issue occur to me and this post led me to fix it.

Comment: I had to make a change to the less file I was editing on order for the error to go away, but simply adding a space and then deleting it worked. Thanks for the info Curt!